# Proof of subfactorial formula $!n = n!- \sum_{i=1}^{n} {{n} \choose {i}} \quad!(n-i)$

Tags: combinatorics, derangements

Any hints about how to prove 
$$!n = n!- \sum_{i=1}^{n} {{n} \choose {i}}\,!(n-i)$$

from 
[Wikipedia's article on derangements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subfactorial)?

Here, $!n$ is the number of derangements of a set with $n$ elements.

I am not looking for proofs, just nudges in the right direction.

Comment: Please do not post the proof if you know it, just ideas are what I am seeking.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Hint: ${{n} \choose {i}} \cdot!(n-i)$ counts the number of permutations that fix exactly $i$ elements.

Comment: Thanks, I will see if that helps.

Comment: Yup, it helps. I believe I have what I need for the proof

Answer (score 5):

I actually prove a generalization of this in my paper "[Deranged Exams](http://math.pugetsound.edu/~mspivey/DT.pdf)" (*College Mathematics Journal*, 41 (3): 197-202, 2010).  See Theorem 7.

The generalization is the following.  Let $S_{n,k}$ be the number of permutations on $n$ elements in which none of the first $k$ elements remains in its original position.  Thus $S_{n,0} = n!$, and the number of derangements on $n$ elements, $D_n$, is $S_{n,n}$.

$$S_{n+k,k} = \sum_{j=0}^n \binom{n}{j} D_{k+j}.$$

The OP's question is the case $k = 0$.

<strike>I'll extract the essence of the proof and post it in the next few minutes.</strike>
Since you want hints rather than a full proof, I'll just leave this as a reference in case you (or anyone else reading this) is interested.  Jonas Meyer's answer gives a good hint.

Comment: Thanks, but I am not looking for a proof

Comment: Nice article! Thanks for sharing, Mike.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a proof, obscured using spoiler space.

> If $d_n$ is the number of derangements on $n$ elements, then the number of permutations on $n$ elements with *exactly* $i$ fixed points is ${n \choose i} d_{n-i}$ (choose i points to fix, then any permutation that fixes exactly those $i$ points (and nothing else) determines a derangement on the non-fixed points, and there are $d_{n-i}$ such derangements).  Hence, $n!=\sum_{i=0}^n {n \choose i} d_{n-i}$, which can be rearranged to give the above formula.

PS. I'm not a fan of the $!n$ notation, I'm pretty sure it's not standard in combinatorics.

Comment: This looks awesome. Well, both the solution and the "spoilering" method. Maybe we should all be doing it for complete solutions...

Comment: See this on meta.SO for how to implement this, http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1191/add-markdown-support-for-hidden-until-you-click-text-aka-spoilers/71396#71396, and this question on meta, http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1349/re-spoiler-space.  Thanks to Douglas Stones for thinking of this and Jonas Meyer for finding out how!

Answer (score 1):

The number of derangements is the number of permutations less the number that leave some numbers fixed.  So for example the term i=5 in the sum is all the ways to pick 5 out of n to leave fixed and derange all the rest.  Then sum over all the numbers of ones that can be fixed.