# Number of permutations of $n$ elements where no number $i$ is in position $i$

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, faq, derangements

I am trying to figure out how many permutations exist in a set where none of the numbers equal their own position in the set; for example, $3,1,5,2,4$ is an acceptable permutation where $3,1,2,4,5$ is not because 5 is in position 5.  I know that the number of total permutations is $n!$.
 Is there a formula for how many are acceptable given the case that no position holds its own number?

Comment: Check out http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement

Comment: This recent math.SE question asks for a proof of one of the formulas for the number of derangements: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/14477/.

Comment: In his combinatorics lecture notes, Jacob Lurie analyses the problem of derangements. It is at the end of these note: http://www.math.harvard.edu/~lurie/155notes/lecture3.pdf and continues into these http://www.math.harvard.edu/~lurie/155notes/lecture4.pdf.

Answer (score 25):

What you are looking for is known as [derangement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement). However, for counting the number of derangement for say $n$-elements you could possible use a trick, compute$\frac{n!}{e}$ and then round off to an integer and this will give you the desired result.

This is actually another application of $e$, which was discovered by Jacob Bernoulli in the problem of derangement, also known as the [hat check problem](https://www.jstor.org/pss/2315337).