# The number of bijections $f$ of $\{1, 2,..., n\}$ such that $f(i) \ne i$ for any $i$

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, permutations

> Show that the number of bijections $f$ of $\{1, 2,..., n\}$ such that
>   $f(i) \ne i$ for any $i$ is equal to $$\sum_{j=0}^{n}(-1)^j\frac{n!}{j!}.$$

Can I get some help for the above problem? I am not getting it at all.

Comment: The permutations you seek are called [derangements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement).

Comment: Similar question: [Number of permutations where n $\ne$ position n](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/14666/number-of-permutations-where-n-position-n)

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Use the principle of inclusion-exclusion with conditions $c_i: f(i) = i$ to find the number of bijections with at least one fixed point. Then subtract this number from the number of all bijections to get the result.

Answer (score 1):

Such bijections are called [derangements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement). The Week $2$ homework *Counting Derangements* [here](http://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/qg-winter2004/) gives one approach, using an [inclusion-exclusion argument](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion-exclusion), while still leaving most of the details to you. (It also has four sets of answers by different people.) You can find full derivations, using a variety of techniques, in any number of books, including Graham, Knuth, & Patashnik, *Concrete Mathematics*, Miklós Bóna, *Introduction to Enumerative Combinatorics*, and Wilf, *generatingfunctionology*; the last is freely available [here](http://www.math.upenn.edu/~wilf/DownldGF.html).

Answer (score 1):

A nice derivation starts with considering a permutation with exactly $k$ fixed points in $n$, there are $\dbinom{n}{k} D_{n - k}$ of those. In all there are $n!$ permutations. This gives the recurrence:
$$
n! = \sum_{0 \le k \le n} \binom{n}{k} D_{n - k}
$$
Define the exponential generating function:
$$
\widehat{D}(z) = \sum_{n \ge 0} D_n \frac{z^n}{n!}
$$
The recurrence is the binomial convolution of 1 and $D_n$, so:
$$
\frac{1}{1 - z} = e^z \widehat{D}(z)
$$
Thus:
$$
\widehat{D}(z) = \frac{e^{-z}}{1 - z}
$$
From this, as multipling by $(1 - z)^{-1}$ gives partial sums of coefficients:
$$
\frac{D_n}{n!} = \sum_{0 \le k \le n} \frac{(-1)^k}{k!}
$$