# How to calculate the probability mass function of $X_N$, the number of people getting back their own hat

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-distributions

How do I calculate the pmf of $X_N$, where $X$ is the number of people out of $N$ getting back their own hat after a random hat exchange?

How can I calculate it without listing all the possible outcomes?

Comment: (Assume everyone got a hat before exchange.)

Comment: How many people do you have ? if $X$ is discrete then he doesn't have a density function, maybe you are looking for the distribution ?

Comment: Right it should be pmf.

Comment: OK, but The answer still depends on how many people you have

Comment: Yes, I will change the $X$ to $X_N$, where $X_n$ could integers be from 0 to N.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** For $0\leq n\leq N$ : $P(X_{N}=n)$ is the probability that
exactly $n$ people got their hat back.

In how many ways this can be done ?

If want to fix some $n$ hats
in their place (in how many ways can we choose them ?) and [dearrange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/14666/number-of-permutations-where-n-position-n)
the other $N-n$ hats (in how many ways can you do that ?)

Comment: Thank you. But I think what you just did was rewriting my question. Also n is from 0. Means no one getting there own hat.

Comment: I think maybe you could show how to get the pmt of N=4 as an example.

Comment: @RHS - this is not a rewrite to your question. the hints are in the last paragraph. Note that the word "dearrange" is a link to guide you do find the number of permutations without fixed points