# Probability that a random permutation has no fixed point among the first $k$ elements

Tags: calculus, probability, combinatorics, analysis, permutations

Is it true that $\frac1{n!} \int_0^\infty x^{n-k} (x-1)^k e^{-x}\,dx \approx e^{-k/n}$ when $k$ and $n$ are large integers with $k \le n$?

This quantity is the probability that a random permutation of $n$ elements does not fix any of the first $k$ elements.

Comment: My few tries on mathematica seem to suggest it is correct.

Comment: Fix $a\in(0,1)$. If $k$ and $n$ go to infinity with $k/n\to a$, Mike's equivalent of $S_{n,k}/n!$ implies that the limit you asked for is $(2-a)/\mathrm{e}$ (I think). On the other hand, Shai's answer implies that this limit is $\mathrm{e}^{-a}$. You accepted Shai's answer and also agreed with the part of Mike's answer which yields the limit $(2-a)/\mathrm{e}$. How is this possible? Which answer do you think is correct?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's a heuristic idea, based on the strong law of large numbers (SLLN). A rigorous proof can be made using the central limit theorem (CLT), as in my new answer.

First write 
$$
I = \frac{1}{{n!}}\int_0^\infty  {x^{n - k} (x - 1)^k e^{ - x} \,{\rm d}x}  = \int_0^\infty  {\bigg(1 - \frac{1}{x}} \bigg)^k \frac{{x^n e^{ - x} }}{{\Gamma (n + 1)}}\,{\rm d}x.
$$
Now, if $X_1,\ldots,X_{n+1}$ are i.i.d. exponential(1) random variables, then their sum $X_1 + \cdots + X_{n+1}$ has gamma density $x^n e^{-x} / \Gamma(n+1)$, $x > 0$. Hence,
$$
I = {\rm E} \bigg[ 1 - \frac{1}{{X_1  +  \cdots  + X_{n + 1} }}\bigg]^k = {\rm E}\bigg[1 - \frac{{n + 1}}{{X_1  +  \cdots  + X_{n + 1} }}\frac{1}{{n + 1}}\bigg]^k .
$$
By SLLN, $(n + 1)^{ - 1} \sum\nolimits_{i = 1}^{n + 1} {X_i }$ converges almost surely to  ${\rm E}[X_1 ] = 1$ as $n \to \infty$. So this suggests the approximation
$$
I \approx \bigg(1 - \frac{1}{{n + 1}}\bigg)^k  = \bigg(1 - \frac{1}{{n + 1}}\bigg)^{n(k/n)}  \approx e^{ - k/n}.
$$

Answer (score 9):

A rigorous proof can be made using the central limit theorem (CLT), as follows.

Since 
$$
\frac{1}{{n!}}\int_0^1  {x^{n - k} (x - 1)^k e^{ - x} \,{\rm d}x} \to 0  
$$
as $n \to \infty$, it suffices to consider the integral from $1$ to $\infty$. Let $c>0$ be arbitrary but fixed, and let $X_i$ be as in my previous answer. Define $f_n {(x)} = x^n e^{-x} / \Gamma(n+1)$, $x>0$, and put $n'=n+1$. Then, since $f_n$ is the density of $\sum\nolimits_{i = 1}^{n'} {X_i }$,
$$
\frac{1}{{n!}}\int_1^{n' - c\sqrt {n'} } {x^{n - k} (x - 1)^k e^{ - x} \,{\rm d}x}  \leq \int_0^{n' - c\sqrt {n'} } {f_n (x)\,{\rm d}x} = {\rm P}\bigg(\frac{{\sum\nolimits_{i = 1}^{n'} {X_i }  - n'}}{{\sqrt {n'} }} \le  - c \bigg).
$$
By the CLT, since the $X_i$ have unit mean and unit variance, the probability on the right-hand side tends to $\Phi(-c)$ as $n \to \infty$, where $\Phi$ denotes the distribution function of the standard normal distribution. 
Similarly,
$$
\frac{1}{{n!}}\int_{n' + c\sqrt {n'} }^\infty  {x^{n - k} (x - 1)^k e^{ - x} \,{\rm d}x}  \leq \int_{{n'} + c\sqrt {n'} }^\infty  {f_n (x)\,{\rm d}x} = {\rm P}\bigg(\frac{{\sum\nolimits_{i = 1}^{n'} {X_i }  - n'}}{{\sqrt {n'} }} > c \bigg),
$$
and, by the CLT, the probability on the right-hand side tends to $1 - \Phi(c)$ as $n \to \infty$.
Next, note that
$$
\bigg(1 - \frac{1}{{n' - c\sqrt {n'} }}\bigg)^k \int_{n' - c\sqrt {n'} }^{n' + c\sqrt {n'} } {f_n (x)\,{\rm d}x} \leq
\frac{1}{{n!}}\int_{n' - c\sqrt {n'} }^{n' + c\sqrt {n'} } {x^{n - k} (x - 1)^k e^{ - x} \,{\rm d}x}
$$
and 
$$
\frac{1}{{n!}}\int_{n' - c\sqrt {n'} }^{n' + c\sqrt {n'} } {x^{n - k} (x - 1)^k e^{ - x} \,{\rm d}x} \leq \bigg(1 - \frac{1}{{n' + c\sqrt {n'} }}\bigg)^k \int_{n' - c\sqrt {n'} }^{n' + c\sqrt {n'} } {f_n (x)\,{\rm d}x}.
$$
By the CLT,
$$
 \int_{n' - c\sqrt {n'} }^{n' + c\sqrt {n'} } {f_n (x)\,{\rm d}x} = {\rm P}\bigg(-c \leq \frac{{\sum\nolimits_{i = 1}^{n'} {X_i }  - n'}}{{\sqrt {n'} }} \leq c \bigg) \to 2 \Phi(c) -1
$$
as $n \to \infty$. Combining it all, and noting that 
$$
\bigg(1 - \frac{1}{{n' \pm c\sqrt {n'} }}\bigg)^k  = \bigg(1 - \frac{1}{{n' \pm c\sqrt {n'} }}\bigg)^{n(k/n)}  \approx e^{ - k/n}, 
$$
the result follows by choosing $c$ sufficiently large. [Note that first we choose $c$ sufficiently large, then we let $n \to \infty$.]

Comment: Fix $a\in(0,1)$. If $k$ and $n$ go to infinity with $k/n\to a$, Mike's equivalent of $S_{n,k}/n!$ implies that the limit asked by the OP is $(2-a)/\mathrm{e}$ (I think). On the other hand, your answer implies that this limit is $\mathrm{e}^{-a}$. Which one is correct?

Comment: @Didier: I'll check this, and let you know (hopefully today).

Comment: @Didier: I confirmed my answer using WolframAlpha and Wims Function Calculator.

Comment: Great. See my comment to Mike's post.

Answer (score 7):

Update: This argument only holds for some cases.  See italicized additions below.

Let $S_{n,k}$ denote the number of permutations in which the first $k$ elements are not fixed.  I published an expository paper on these numbers earlier this year.  See "[Deranged Exams](http://math.pugetsound.edu/~mspivey/DT.pdf)," (College Mathematics Journal, 41 (3): 197-202, 2010).  Aravind's formula is in the paper, as are several others involving $S_{n,k}$ and related numbers.

Theorem 7 (which I also mention in [this recent math.SE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/14477/)) is relevant to this question.  It's
$$S_{n+k,k} = \sum_{j=0}^n \binom{n}{j} D_{k+j},$$
where $D_n$ is the number of derangements on $n$ elements.  See the paper for a simple combinatorial proof of this.

Since $D_n$ grows as $n!$ via $D_n = \frac{n!}{e} + O(1)$ (see Wikipedia's page on the [derangement numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement#Counting_derangements)), and *if $k$ is much larger than $n$*,
the dominant terms in the probability
$\frac{S_{n+k,k}}{(n+k)!}$ are the $j = n$ and $j = n-1$ terms from the Theorem 7 expression.  Thus we have 
$$\frac{S_{n+k,k}}{(n+k)!} \approx \frac{D_{n+k} + n D_{n+k-1}}{(n+k)!} \approx \frac{1}{e}\left(1  + \frac{n}{n+k}\right) \approx e^{-1} e^{\frac{n}{n+k}} = e^\frac{-k}{n+k},$$
where the second-to-last step uses the first two terms in the Maclaurin series expansion for $e^x$.

*Again, this argument holds only for (in my notation) $k$ much larger than $n$.*

Comment: I agree with everything except $1 + \frac{n}{n+k} \approx e^{\frac{n}{n+k}}$, which doesn't hold because $\frac{n}{n+k}$ is not close to 0.

Comment: @Dave R: I've thought about this for the past couple of hours and almost posted a more precise estimate, but I think the simplest way past the difficulty really is that my argument works unless $n$ is large relative to $k$ (which would make $\frac{n}{n+k} \approx 1$).  But if this is the case, then Hans Lundmark's answer (in my notation) shows that the probability is approximately $1 - \frac{k}{n+k} \approx e^{\frac{-k}{n+k}}$.  So I think between my answer and Hans's you have the argument you need.  (And I will now upvote Hans's and Aravind's answers accordingly.)

Comment: @Mike Fix $a\in(0,1)$. If $k$ and $n$ go to infinity with $k/n\to a$, your equivalent of $S_{n,k}/n!$ implies that the limit asked by the OP is $(2-a)/\mathrm{e}$ (I think). On the other hand, Shai's answer implies that this limit is $\mathrm{e}^{-a}$. Which one is correct?

Comment: @Didier: Good question.  Let me think about it.

Comment: @Didier: With your comment and the OP's I'm realizing that my argument only applies for certain values of $n$ and $k$.  In my notation, we need $k$ to remain much larger than $n$ in order to have the approximation $1 + \frac{n}{n+k} \approx e^{\frac{n}{n+k}}$ be a good one.  So one can't hold that ratio you mention constant and then use my argument to get an accurate limiting value.  I haven't checked Shai's work myself, but if I had to choose between $(2-a)/e$ and $e^{-a}$ for the limiting value, I would go with the latter.

Comment: @Mike Thanks for your answer. Thus, your argument is restricted to the asymptotics of $S_{n,k}/n!$ in the regime $n=k+\ell$ with $\ell\to+\infty$ and $\ell=o(k)$, and you prove that in this regime, the asymptotics is $1/\mathrm{e}$. This is the case $a=1$ of my question and, for $a=1$, $(2-a)/\mathrm{e}=\mathrm{e}^{-a}$, hence there is no contradiction with Shai's answer.

Answer (score 6):

This is not an answer but an observation that the quantity is equal to $\sum_{i=0}^{k} \frac{{(-1)}^i}{n!}{k \choose i}(n-i)!$.

Answer (score 3):

Continuing Aravind's observation, write it like
$$
1 - \frac{k}{n} + \frac{1}{2!} \left( \frac{k}{n} \right)^2 \frac{1-1/k}{1-1/n}
- \frac{1}{3!} \left( \frac{k}{n} \right)^3 \frac{(1-1/k)(1-2/k)}{(1-1/n)(1-2/n)}
$$
$$+ \dots
+ (-1)^k \frac{1}{k!} \left( \frac{k}{n} \right)^k \frac{(1-1/k)(1-2/k)\dots (1-(k-1)/k)}{(1-1/n)(1-2/n) \dots (1-(k-1)/n)}.
$$
If $k$ and $n$ are large, this seems to be close to the $k$th degree Maclaurin polynomial
for $e^z$ evaluated at $z=-k/n$ (although I don't have an estimate of the error).